# “The app you shared from doesn't currently support sharing to Stories.” error when sharing to instagram stories as a third-party app

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-story

My mobile apps have previously integrated with Instagram Sharing to Stories both on iOS and Android. Recently, some users started seeing the “The app you shared from doesn't currently support sharing to Stories.” error on the UI after they tap on the sharing button and land in Instagram, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAOx2.gif).

In another instance, ther users are seeing the error message "The app you shared from doesn't currently support sharing to Instagram." instead.

What could be the issue here?

I'm expecting Instagram to open the stories editor with the preloaded media shared from my app, but instead, it's showing the main feed view with the error message on the bottom.

Answer (score 7):

This is due to a Facebook App ID requirement recently enforced by Instagram on  January 30, 2023.

You can find their blog post at https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2022/10/10/introducing-important-update-to-Instagram-sharing-to-stories/, as well as their developer documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories/.

To fix this issue, you would need to register your app on the Facebook developer console at https://developers.facebook.com/, obtain a Facebook app ID and pass it as the source_application param in your integrations.

Comment: Thanks adding facebook ID resolved issue. For react native and instagram share story I updated the library and added the ID https://react-native-share.github.io/react-native-share/docs/share-single#facebook